# Problems mutate-ing and select-ing over a list of tibbles

Tags: r, dplyr, emmeans

I'm trying to reproduce a graph from Clause Willke's data visualization guide (https://clauswilke.com/dataviz/visualizing-uncertainty.html#fig:cocoa-data-vs-CI), and the code he wrote is choking for me.

I apologize in advance if this is long, but trying to explain what I think is going on. (Also, you can find the `cacao` data at https://github.com/clauswilke/dviz.supp/blob/master/data/cacao.rda.)

Full code chunk:

```
cacao %>% 
  filter(location == "Canada") -> cacao_single

fit <- lm(rating ~ 1, data = cacao_single)

CI_df <- data.frame(type = c(0.8, 0.95, 0.99)) %>%
  mutate(df = map(type, ~tidy(emmeans(fit, ~ 1, options = list(level = .x)
  )))) %>%
  unnest(c()) %>%
  select(type, estimate, std.error, conf.low, conf.high) %>%
  mutate(type = paste0(signif(100*type, 2), "% confidence interval"))
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `estimate` doesn't exist.
```

The emmeans() function normally returns the beta estimate, SE, df, and upper and lower confidence bounds, as in:

```
> emmeans(fit, ~1)
 1       emmean     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 overall   3.32 0.0379 124     3.25      3.4

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

When I run the piped statement above, I get a list of tibbles, but the list-element tibbles do not have CIs attached. This is in addition to the `select()` not finding `estimate` (as the error message appears to indicate). Thus,

1. Why doesn't the list of tibbles have the CIs associated with each confidence level in the `type` column? Should it?
2. How can I get `select()` to, well, select?

Comment: Did you check `dplyr::select()`?

Comment: As in read the `help()` for it? Yes. I don't think `select()` works because those are not the name of the columns?

I think that this has to do with the **very complex** statement in the first `mutate()` line, where we `mutate` over the vector "type" on a `map`-ping of type to a `tidy`-ed `emmeans` where the CI level is the current value of "type" for all values of "type."

If `emmeans()` were coming out of that statement "properly", then `select()` would be able to pick the appropriate column, I think. So I'm not sure my second question attains, TBH.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `c()` in `unnest()` (it gives a warning but it works).  It may be that `unnest()` syntax has changed.

```r
CI_df <- data.frame(type = c(0.8, 0.95, 0.99)) %>%
  mutate(df = map(type, ~generics::tidy(emmeans(fit, ~ 1, options = list(level = .x)
  ))))  %>%
  #unnest(c()) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  select(type, estimate, std.error, conf.low, conf.high) %>%
  mutate(type = paste0(signif(100*type, 2), "% confidence interval"))
```

Comment: When I run
```CI_df <- data.frame(type = c(0.8, 0.95, 0.99)) %>%
  mutate(df = map(type, ~tidy(emmeans(fit, ~ 1, options = list(level = .x)
  )))) %>%
  unnest(df) %>%
  select(type, estimate, std.error, conf.low, conf.high) %>%
  mutate(type = paste0(signif(100*type, 2), "% confidence interval"))```
R returns: 
```Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `conf.low` doesn't exist.```

I'm more sure that this is something to do with the first `mutate()` not correctly creating the high and low CI estimates.

Comment: The above code runs for me. I have `dplyr` version 1.0.0.   and `tidyr` version 1.1.0.  Did you try to see if the first `mutate()` runs by commenting out the rest?

Comment: Below `mutate()`? Yes. It runs, but does not generate the high and low CI columns (although emmeans normally does if one runs `emmeans(x, ~1)` or `emmeans(x, ~1, level = 0.80)`.

Comment: Note that I had to add prefix in `generics::tidy` in the particular R environment I was running. When namespace conflict arises, it's good to check which package you are referring to.  Did you try that?

Comment: I do get a data frame with colnames = 'type' and 'df' after  `data.frame(type = c(0.8, 0.95, 0.99)) %>%
  mutate(df = map(type, ~generics::tidy(emmeans(fit, ~ 1, options = list(level = .x)
  )))) ` where column 'df' is a list column.  This is then processed by `unnest()`.

Comment: I did add the prefix, but I seem to get the same result as without the prefix.

Comment: after the first mutate(), do you see the list column in 'df'?

Comment: I get the same data frame as you do, except it is missing elements from `emmeans` (the CIs). It does pull over the estimate, SE, d(egrees)f(reedom), statistic (F-test), and p-value.

Comment: Bloody hell. `emmeans` actually uses its summary method in interactive mode, but in a script, it's just the emmeans object and not its summary version. Adding `summary()` around the `emmeans` command seems to make the difference.

Comment: Okay, I am not familiar with `emmeans`'s behavior in interactive mode v script mode but did it solve the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222736/discussion-between-km-83-and-nate).

Comment: emmenns() returns an emmGrid object. Use confint(emmeans(...)) if you want a data frame that includes the confidence limits